# I am having a very hard time with compositing

Tags: compositing-nodes, tracking

I have tracked drone footage, and imported a building model to put in my scene. In viewport shading, everything looks as it should. in rendered view, the movie clip is not taking up the full camera frame as it did in viewport shading, the ground plane now has the video footage (but only in the area of the plane that is within the camera frame) and the background is showing the sky texture i have added. Then, if i switch to cycles, the plane just turns pitch black. I am very lost. Please help. [image]

Comment: You may have overlapping faces, which causes "Z fighting", select your plane, switch to Edit mode, select all and press M > Merge by Distance

Comment: I actually was given the answer by a friend. In the compositor theres a node that gets autogenerated for the composit setup. Its called undistortions, i duplicated that, and put it between the 2 alpha over nodes, and switched it to distort. This fixed the issue.